# Building multiple Erlang Beam files?

Tags: erlang

I am currently using

```
c(module_name)
```

to build my Erlang files one by one. How can the build process for Erlang be handle when they have multiple files?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Everyone should probably be using the official build tool for Erlang: [rebar3](https://rebar3.org/). It did not exist when I provided this older answer:

I start out by using [Erlang make](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html), because it starts the VM once and compiles everything that needs to be recompiled.

Try the following in your source directory, it will compile those .erl files that are missing a corresponding Beam file or those where the .erl file has been modified since the Beam file was compiled:

```
erl -make
```

Learn about Emakefile for additional tricks, such as compiling all source files with debug_info and placing the .beam files in ebin:

```
{'*',
    [{outdir,"../ebin"},
    debug_info]}.
```

Answer (score 16):

This compiles everything in the directory you're currently in:

```
cover:compile_directory().
```

Answer (score 5):

a lot of projects use a regular old make file and `erlc`

```
erlc -h
Usage:  erlc [options] file.ext ...
Options:
-b type        type of output file (e.g. jam or beam)
-d             turn on debugging of erlc itself
-Dname         define name
-Dname=value   define name to have value
-hybrid        compile using hybrid-heap emulator
-help          shows this help text
-I path        where to search for include files
-o name        name output directory or file
-pa path       add path to the front of Erlang's code path
-pz path       add path to the end of Erlang's code path
-smp           compile using SMP emulator
-v             verbose compiler output
-Werror        make all warnings into errors
-W0            disable warnings
-Wnumber       set warning level to number
-Wall          enable all warnings
-W             enable warnings (default; same as -W1)
-E             generate listing of expanded code (Erlang compiler)
-S             generate assembly listing (Erlang compiler)
-P             generate listing of preprocessed code (Erlang compiler)
+term          pass the Erlang term unchanged to the compiler
```

Answer (score 1):

[Erlang Make and Emakefiles](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/make.html) are probably a good way to start.

As an example, you might want to have a look to the build system of [Erlang Web](http://bitbucket.org/etc/erlang-web/).

In the specific, you might want to look at their [Emakefile](http://bitbucket.org/etc/erlang-web/src/tip/Emakefile) and their [compile.erl](http://bitbucket.org/etc/erlang-web/src/tip/bin/compile.erl).

Answer (score 1):

*You can use 'rebar', an Erlang build tool from Basho that is OTP compliant: this sets up multiple erlang applications into a consistent directory structure and allows you to do more than just compile files into .beams. [rebar compile]*

For instance, you can
     * run tests (eUnit + feature/regression) [rebar test]

```
 - build releases [rebar rel]
 - start ci-builds 
 - specify dependencies from multiple sources in its config file
 - enable SNMPwalks through data collected by SNMP agents of various types
 - (in conjunction with xref and grapherl) generate call graphs of entire applications
 - (in conjunction with fprof and fprof_graph) generate profiling diagrams
 - run dialyzer to do static code analysis
```

**To see all rebar commands, 'rebar -c' will give you a complete picture.**

rebar is from Basho with variants floating around, :-)

You can get rebar [here](https://github.com/basho/rebar)

The [wiki](https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki) says it all.